# When she _____ dinner, her husband came home. (was making) or (had made)

Tags: grammar

Which one of these is grammatically correct?

> When she was making dinner, her husband came home.
>
> When she had made dinner, her husband came home.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please see "How can I ask about checking my text" in our [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=How%20can%20I%20ask%20about%20checking%20my%20text%3F). Although you have an answer, questions of this type generally need to state what you already know, so that the best help can be given.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are both grammatically correct. The first example is better than the second example, but you probably wouldn't say either sentence because the word "When" isn't specific enough to communicate the intent.

In the first example, "While" is a better word to indicate that she was in the process of making dinner when her husband came home.

> While she was making dinner, her husband came home.

In the second example, "After" is a better word to indicate that she had finished making dinner when her husband came home.

> After she had made dinner, her husband came home.

Comment: Of course the second could also be interpreted as: “She had long since given up making dinner.  When she had made dinner, her husband came home, but now he was known to stay out sometimes until the early morning.”

Comment: @Jim Then it would be “her husband had come home,” I think.

Comment: @Xanne - I think it works either way.